# CocoaPods use_frameworks! causes "Class X is implemented in both Y and Z"

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I want to integrate some obj-c libraries into my Swift project via `CocoaPods v0.37.2`.

Here is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
pod "FBSDKCoreKit", '~> 4.2.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.2.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.2.0'
end
```

I always got the following message on console when running my project on a simulator:

> objc[40546]: Class FBSDKAccessToken is implemented in both /Users/brian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2146BB4A-B290-4538-A090-41DA702BD959/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8F5457C5-253A-4E65-B21A-12438B642201/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit and /Users/brian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2146BB4A-B290-4538-A090-41DA702BD959/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8F5457C5-253A-4E65-B21A-12438B642201/MyApp.app/MyApp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

(I got lots of similar messages, this is only an example)

I am sure it's caused by `use_frameworks!`. If I remove this statement from my Podfile and use a bridging-header, this error disappears and everything is good.

I've googled for a while, but it seems nobody got this error on the Internet.

How do I get rid of this error while using `use_frameworks!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't use `use_frameworks!` from the beginning and used it after I started working on my project. This triggered a bug that made there are 2 sources of the same libs on my simulators and threw this error.

Removing the simulators and adding it back again saved me. (Resetting the simulators doesn't work, you must remove the simulators and add them back via `Window > Devices`)